# What is the meaning of ${$"\x47L"... this syntax in PHP?

Tags: php

I found some malicious code inside my php pages, and I understand that the obfuscation is being used, but I never saw syntax like that in PHP.

example 1)

```
${"\x47LOB\x41\x4c\x53"}["\x76\x72vw\x65y\x70\x7an\x69\x70\x75"]="a";
```

example 2)

```
${${"\x47\x4c\x4f\x42\x41LS"}["\x64\x77\x65\x6dbj\x63"]}="\x23d\x665";
```

So the question is what is the meaning of that code, and how does the PHP process it. I'm mostly curious about "${" in the begining of the line.

Thanks.

Comment: This is coming from a malicious php webshell most known as c99madshell.
Use http://beta.phpformatter.com to decode it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a [hexadecimal escape sequence](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

`\x47` corresponds to `G`, `\x41` corresponds to `A`, etc.

The code you posted translates to:

`${"GLOBALS"}["vrvweypznipu"]="a";`
and
`${${"GLOBALS"}["dwembjc"]}="#df5";`

The `${}` notation is usually used for [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).  It allows you to access named variables using strings.

Comment: So this lines actually produce the same result: echo $${a}; echo $$a; echo ${$a};if you assign it as variable variable, a bit loose syntax, thanks for quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Mr. Llama's answer, the sequences are basically referring to the $GLOBALS array in PHP:
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

edit: Mr Llama has now expanded his answer to include the above.